# Yii2 Composer manage package in bower and bower-vendor

Tags: yii2, composer-php

I have been using yii2 for sometime now but i cant wrap my head around how to manage my packages. I have two issues in these regard.

1. when i add a package to yii2 it is downloaded in vendor/bower/bower-assets.
2. when yii2 is publishing the packages it looks for the assets under vendor/bower

How do i fix this. I have a number of yii2 installations for different projects and i seem to run to the same problem every single time.

Here is my composer.json file

```
{
    "name": "yiisoft/yii2-app-basic",
    "description": "Yii 2 Basic Project Template",
    "keywords": ["yii2", "framework", "basic", "project template"],
    "homepage": "http://www.yiiframework.com/",
    "type": "project",
    "license": "BSD-3-Clause",
    "support": {
        "issues": "https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues?state=open",
        "forum": "http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/",
        "wiki": "http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/",
        "irc": "irc://irc.freenode.net/yii",
        "source": "https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "stable",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.4.0",
        "yiisoft/yii2": ">=2.0.5",
        "yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap": "*",
        "yiisoft/yii2-swiftmailer": "*",
        "dektrium/yii2-user": "0.9.*@dev"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "yiisoft/yii2-codeception": "*",
        "yiisoft/yii2-debug": "*",
        "yiisoft/yii2-gii": "*",
        "yiisoft/yii2-faker": "*"
    },
    "config": {
        "process-timeout": 1800
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "yii\\composer\\Installer::postCreateProject"
        ]
    },
    "extra": {
        "yii\\composer\\Installer::postCreateProject": {
            "setPermission": [
                {
                    "runtime": "0777",
                    "web/assets": "0777",
                    "yii": "0755"
                }
            ],
            "generateCookieValidationKey": [
                "config/web.php"
            ]
        },
        "asset-installer-paths": {
            "npm-asset-library": "vendor/npm",
            "bower-asset-library": "vendor/bower"
        }
    }
}
```

See below my AppAsset File

```
class AppAsset extends AssetBundle
{
    public $basePath = '@webroot';
    public $baseUrl = '@web';
    public $css = [
        'css/site.css',
    ];
    public $js = [
    ];
    public $depends = [
        'yii\web\YiiAsset',
        'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapAsset',
    ];
}
```

Comment: So you want to include those assets in your asset bundle ?

Comment: @TNC Yes i want to include these assets or define the alias '@bower'  to point to vendor/bower/bower-assets as this is the default installation location for the composer packages

Comment: Install fxp asset plugin globally.

Comment: @schmunk I have installed already fxp asset plugin globally. My major issue is that packages are been downloaded to '@vendor/bower/bower-assets' but all applications are publishing assets on '@vendor/bower' should i overwrite the  alias '@bower'. Kindly advise

Comment: @chapskev I usually saw errors like this, when `asset-installer-paths` was not parsed correctly, this setting should take care about the locations and is handled by fxp's asset-plugin.
But anyway, as a workaround you may try to override the aliases you mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be archived by overwriting the default alias path for bower packages which is @vendor/bower to  @vendor/bower/bower-asset.

This can be done from the web.php file under $config=[]

```
 'aliases' => [
        '@bower' => '@vendor/bower/bower-asset',
    ],
```

when you echo

```
echo Yii::getAlias('@bower');
```

it should echo

```
/Library/WebServer/Documents/project-name/vendor/bower/bower-asset
```

Answer (score 1):

I faced this issue a little while ago, and it drove me crazy!

The solution is actually quite simple (isn't it always?) - you need to delete the *fxp* directory in your Composer common directory and clear the composer cache - `composer global clearcache` - and remove the fxp plugin line from your global composer.json and re-require it.

No matter what I did, the bower packages was installed in *vendor/bower/bower-asset* or other weird places.

The solution that helped me was to get rid of the fxp plugin and re-require it.
Try that.

The Composer asset plugin is buggy, but useful.

Hope this helps ! :)

Edit:
The problem that you are facing is simply that the Composer assets plugin refuses to parse the asset installation paths that is clearly defined in your composer.json file.
After having tested the behaviour in my own project, I created a 'vanilla' basic application and even an advanced application: same behaviour.
So, I re-required/re-installed the asset plugin and that fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

This is how we register booty assets.

```
namespace backend\assets;


use yii\web\AssetBundle;

class BootstrapAsset extends AssetBundle
{
    public $sourcePath = '@bower/bootstrap/dist';
    public $js         = [
        'js/bootstrap.min.js',
    ];
}
```

And Register this asset in your layout as:

```
$asset     = AppAsset::register($this);
$bootstrap = \backend\assets\BootstrapAsset::register($this);
```

Hope this will give a hint.

Comment: thank for your input and contribution. I appreciate it. I don't want to create an asset bundle i want to change the core files path i.e. JQuery, Bootstrap e.t.c. I have found a work around it :) thanks