# what a part does bower/bower-asset play in php application such as yii2

Tags: yii2, composer-php, bower

Recently I  deployed some projects like  [trntv/yii2-starter-kit](https://github.com/trntv/yii2-starter-kit/) and so on.but all applications are publishing assets on '@vendor/bower' instead of'@vendor/bower/bower-asset'. I have read the question [Yii2 Composer manage package in bower and bower-vendor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34872504/yii2-composer-manage-package-in-bower-and-bower-vendor) and solved it . but I still feel confused about the directory `vendor/bower/bower-asset`.
What's the part does bower/bower-asset play in php application? it is not a composer package but many theme store in there. Furthermore, `bower` is a dependency management for javascript just like `Composer` for PHP , but how does it solve dependency for js package by PHP on this occasion that I have not install node.js environment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea of Composer Asset Plugin is to download Bower / NPM packages and manage their dependencies without having Node JS, Bower and NPM installed (through PHP / Composer). Also it adds possibility to add JavaScript dependencies for PHP packages that use JavaScript libraries.

See for example [yii2-bootstrap](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap/blob/master/composer.json) Yii2 extension (PHP) has a dependency on Bootstrap (JS + CSS):

```
"bower-asset/bootstrap": "3.3.* | 3.2.* | 3.1.*"
```

When you run `composer install` or `composer update`, all JS dependencies will be installed to `vendor/bower` folder.

This is built into the core, but very ambiguous, receives a lot of criticism and there are plans to remove it in `2.1.0` (as far as I remember, it was included before release of `2.0` even it was unstable). Unfortunately this is required and there is no normal way to disable it.

You can read more info on the extension's [Github page](https://github.com/francoispluchino/composer-asset-plugin).

As for folder name, it should be named `bower`, not `bower-asset`, if you installed everything correctly.

It's named like so automatically, make sure you have the latest version of plugin:

```
composer global require "fxp/composer-asset-plugin:~1.1.1"
```

I'd recommend to even switch to:

```
composer global require "fxp/composer-asset-plugin:*"
```

If you have problems or errors, execute:

```
composer global remove "fxp/composer-asset-plugin"
```

Then reinstall it again, delete `vendor` and `composer.lock` in your application folder and run:

```
composer install
```